# (ngModelChange) not triggers the function in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I have two input fields and when I enter any number value in input field 1 (dummy1) it should update the input field 2 (dummy2). Once input field 2 is updated, it should trigger the `successMessage()`. But it is not happening. the value is getting changed in input 2(dummy2). But the `successMessage()` function is not triggered. I thought `(ngModelChange)` would trigger the function as the dummy2 value is updated in updateDummy2() function. please let me know if any ways to call the `successMessage()` function when dummy2 value is updated by the dummy1.

Component.html

```
<div id="dummyWrapper">
  <input id="dummy1" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="dummy1" (ngModelChange)="updateDummy2()" />
  <input id="dummy2" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="dummy2" (ngModelChange)="successMessage()" />
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
public dummy1 = 0;
public dummy2 = 0;




updateDummy2() {
    console.log("updateDummy2")
    this.dummy2 = Number(this.dummy1) + 20;
  }

  successMessage() {
    console.log("success")
  }
```

Or should I go for the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **two way** binding, so below code will not take effect. Use property binding instead.

```
[(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum"  
(ngModelChange)="setThresholds()
```

Or make use of getter setter